# Cannot resolve symbol c882c94be45fff9d16a1cf845fc16ec5

Tags: java, android, weather-api, openweathermap, buildconfig

I am a new developer exploring the world of Android. I am currently working through the Udacity tutorials for creating the Sunshine app. In the fragment activity class in order to get data from openweathermap I must add the API key I got from my account to the end of the generated URL. There is a call to BuildConfig.java in the [Fragment activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xD2OG.png) (click to see the call to BuildConfig.java which is on the 6th line as part of String apiKey).

The build.gradle file is as follows:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "23.0.1"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.android.sunshine.app"
        minSdkVersion 10
        targetSdkVersion 21
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }

    }
    buildTypes.each {
        it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', 'c882c94be45fff9d16a1cf845fc16ec5'
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'
}
```

in buildTypes.each it.buildConfigField is called with 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', 'c882c94be45fff9d16a1cf845fc16ec5' resulting in

```
public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY = c882c94be45fff9d16a1cf845fc16ec5;
```

being generated in BuildConfig.java, however I keep getting this error:
[Cannot Resolve Symbol](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymmA7.png) (click to see error message and BuildConfig.java file)
I do not understand why the String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY is automatically being created as just a group of letters and numbers without quotes around them, but if I edit the code to read:

```
public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY = "c882c94be45fff9d16a1cf845fc16ec5";
```

or

```
public static final String OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY = 'c882c94be45fff9d16a1cf845fc16ec5';
```

the BuildConfig.java automatically changes itself.
I am not sure what I am doing wrong and I checked many of the Udacity videos which did not have any information about this issue. Please let me know if you know how to fix this.

Regards.

Comment: You might want to generate a new API key at Open Weather Maps if you haven't done so already as anybody could use your key in their app.

Comment: @sornars, very good observation. To all, when putting private and confidential information, like owner API Key in this case, always put dummy value.

Comment: don't worry I changed my API key

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Change

```
 buildTypes.each {
     it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', 'c882c94be45fff9d16a1cf845fc16ec5'
 }
```

with

```
 buildTypes.each {
     it.buildConfigField 'String', 'OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY', "\"c882c94be45fff9d16a1cf845fc16ec5\""
 }
```

this way `OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY` should be escaped correctly

Comment: Can you explain why it needs to be formatted like this?

Comment: @thecog the reason is the both gradle's buildConfigField and Java's strings have to be enclosed into a pair of ""

Comment: I noticed that '"appid"' works as well (single double double single).

Comment: AppId doesn't end up in BuildConfig.java

Comment: Should it? The OPEN_WEATHER_MAP_API_KEY variable appears in BuildConfig.java (with the value defined in build.gradle) for me.

Comment: No it can't. Only what is declared with buildConfigField explicitly by you, and "default "  values apper there

Answer (score 3):

```
    "\"c882c94be45fff9d16a1cf845fc16ec5\""
```

This is the correct syntax for making changes to the BuildTypes container.